# NULL output from lapply and trycatch

Tags: r, try-catch, lapply

I'm trying to speed up my code by replacing for loops with lapply.  I'm running nls models on lots of different samples and extracting the coefs but some of the models do not converge for some samples.  I could handle this with a for loop with trycatch to ignore those samples but I can't get it to work with lapply.  When I run this I get a list of my sample.code and NULL, where should I place the return(nls.dat)? part so I don't just end up the NULL?

```
test.func <- function (SCDF){
  tryCatch({
  mod.allDIDO <- nlsLM (BM~Cr*(1 - R * exp(-Kr*day) - (1 - R) * exp(-Kr2*day)), data=dat[dat$sample.code %in% SC,], start=list(Cr=DI.Cr,R=DI.r,Kr=DI.Kr,Kr2=DI.Kr2),
                        control = nls.lm.control(maxiter = 500), lower = c(-Inf, 0, 0, 0), upper = c(Inf, 1, Inf, Inf))
  nls.dat <- c("df", coef(mod.allDIDO)[1], coef(mod.allDIDO)[2], coef(mod.allDIDO)[3], coef(mod.allDIDO)[4], deviance(mod.allDIDO), logLik(mod.allDIDO))
  return (nls.dat)
  }, error = function(e){})
}

test1 <- lapply(split(dat, dat$sample.code), test.func)
```

Edited to include some data and reply to Carl:
I tried your suggestion (Carl) but I still get NULL, see cut down version

```
x1 <- 0:60
y1 <- 774*(1 - 0.5 * exp(-0.2*x1) - (1 - 0.5) * exp(-0.016*x1))
test.dat <- data.frame (x1, y1)

  nls.dat <- tryCatch({
    mod.allDIDO <- nlsLM(y1~Cr*(1 - R * exp(-Kr*x1) - (1 - R) * exp(-Kr2*x1)), 
                         data=test.dat, 
                         start=list(Cr=774,R=0.5,Kr=0.2,Kr2=0.016),
                         control = nls.lm.control(maxiter = 500), 
                         lower = c(-Inf, 0, 0, 0), 
                         upper = c(Inf, 1, Inf, Inf))
    nls.dat <- c("df", coef(mod.allDIDO)[1], 
                 coef(mod.allDIDO)[2], 
                 coef(mod.allDIDO)[3], 
                 coef(mod.allDIDO)[4], 
                 deviance(mod.allDIDO), 
                 logLik(mod.allDIDO))
    return(nls.dat)
  }, error = function(e){})

  nls.dat  ## NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to pay attention to is your calling environments. Within the `tryCatch` brackets are treating the contained calls as their own functions. So you need to return the retuirn of the `tryCatch` to the parent environment and then return from the function, like so:

```
test.func <- function (SCDF){
  nls.dat <- tryCatch({
    mod.allDIDO <- nlsLM(BM~Cr*(1 - R * exp(-Kr*day) - (1 - R) * exp(-Kr2*day)), 
                         data=dat[dat$sample.code %in% SC,], 
                         start=list(Cr=DI.Cr,R=DI.r,Kr=DI.Kr,Kr2=DI.Kr2),
                         control = nls.lm.control(maxiter = 500), 
                         lower = c(-Inf, 0, 0, 0), 
                         upper = c(Inf, 1, Inf, Inf))

    nls.dat <- c("df", coef(mod.allDIDO)[1], 
                 coef(mod.allDIDO)[2], 
                 coef(mod.allDIDO)[3], 
                 coef(mod.allDIDO)[4], 
                 deviance(mod.allDIDO), 
                 logLik(mod.allDIDO))
    return(nls.dat)
  }, error = function(e){
    NULL
  })
  return(nls.dat)
}
```

## Edit

That's strange behavior... so I tested another way that I would never do... but for some reason it works...
New function takes the variable and adds an `if` statement to add another...seemingly unnecessary logical check.. but it works. Checks if the value is NULL, if not returns, and if there is an error anywhere in the two steps... it would default to the `error = function(e) {NULL}`

```
f <- function(x1, y1, test.dat){
    tryCatch({
        mod.allDIDO <- nlsLM(y1~Cr*(1 - R * exp(-Kr*x1) - (1 - R) * exp(-Kr2*x1)), 
                         data=test.dat, 
                         start=list(Cr=774,R=0.5,Kr=0.2,Kr2=0.016),
                         control = nls.lm.control(maxiter = 500), 
                         lower = c(-Inf, 0, 0, 0), 
                         upper = c(Inf, 1, Inf, Inf))
    nls.dat <- c("df", coef(mod.allDIDO)[1], 
                 coef(mod.allDIDO)[2], 
                 coef(mod.allDIDO)[3], 
                 coef(mod.allDIDO)[4], 
                 deviance(mod.allDIDO), 
                 logLik(mod.allDIDO))
    if(!is.null(nls.dat)){
        return(nls.dat)
    }else {
        NULL
    }
}, error = function(e){NULL})
}
```

and running...

```
> f(x1 = x1, y1 = y1, test.dat = test.dat)
             Cr       R      Kr     Kr2                 
   "df"   "774"   "0.5"   "0.2" "0.016"     "0"   "Inf"
```

Comment: Hi Carl, I tried your suggestion but the output was still NULL, see the cut down version and some data in the edited question.

Comment: above works post-edit... thanks for the data. Also helpful if you include packages you are using..had to hunt down `minpack.lm`. No clue why the logical double-take is helpful...but it works.

Comment: Thanks Carl, this works great, sorry I forgot to add the package.